# Apache poi-3.17 creating an extra null column in Excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am creating an excel sheet using Apache poi-3.17. When the excel sheet is opened, it looks okay, but the same when opened in MS Access, a new blank column gets added in the end. This behavior is only observed with poi-3.17 version and not in any other versions(have tried with 3.11, 3.7, 5.18,4.*). Can somebody please help me with this?

The code that I am using is as below.

```
public static String createExcel(String test) {
    String encodedBase64 = "";
    try {
        System.out.println("Start of method : Test : " + test);
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;

        docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("Data");
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("TEST1");
        XSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
        cell1.setCellValue("TEST2");
        workbook.write(baos);

        try {
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            File file = new File("C:\\Files\\test.xlsx");

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(baos.toByteArray());
            out.close();
       workbook.close();
            encodedBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes).trim();
            System.out.println("encodedBase64 :" + encodedBase64);
           
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Message :" + e.getMessage());
        }<kbd>your text</kbd>

    } 
    return encodedBase64;
}
```

I also tried using row.removeCell(getCell(2)) just to see if it fetches any extra column but it gives nullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this question to show why it's recommended to **always** use the latest version of Apache POI.

**Short answer**

This was a bug in Apache POI version 3.17 while setting the dimension field of a `XSSFSheet`. It was fixed in Version 4.0.0. But Apache POI will not fix bugs in prevoius version's code. Versions before 3.17 didn't have that bug because they didn't set the dimension field of a `XSSFSheet` at all.

So my recommendation is: **Always** use latest Apache POI version (5.2.3 for now).

**Problem**

In result `*.xlsx` file the `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` has the wrong dimension set. It sets the dimension one column too big.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreateXSSF {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("Data");
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

   XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("TEST1");
   XSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
   cell1.setCellValue("TEST2");
   
   workbook.write(fileout);   
  }
 }
}
```

Using Apache POI 3.17:

```
<dimension ref="A1:C1"/>
```

One column too big.

Using current Apache POI 5.2.3:

```
<dimension ref="A1:B1"/>
```

**Reason**

Code of Apache POI 3.17 [XSSFSheet.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l3501) sets `maxCell = Math.max(maxCell, row.getLastCellNum())` and then uses that `maxCell` to set the dimension reference. But `Row.getLastCellNum` will get the index of the last cell contained in this row **PLUS ONE**.

Code of Apache POI 4.0.0 [XSSFSheet.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l3624) corrects this and do `maxCell = Math.max(maxCell, row.getLastCellNum()-1)`.

**Is there a workaround for Apache POI 3.17?**

Not really. `XSSFSheet` method `protected void write(OutputStream out)` gets called while `XSSFWorkbook.write`.   So even if one would set the correct dimension in `XSSFSheet` XML before write, that would overwritten when writing.

One could change the source code of `XSSFSheet.java` in Apache POI 3.17 and then using a new compiled version of that. But why? Why not using current version which has that bug fixed?

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex for  the response. So I know now this cannot be fixed with 3.17 version! So, our application server(weblogic) comes with apache poi 3.17 which is oracle approved version. So even if my SOA project has the latest version of poi and mentioned in project's classpath, when it is deployed on the server, it is still referring the server's poi jar files rather than taking it from my project. I am also trying to figure out a way to override the server's jar files .